# get context in converter?

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a usercontrol whose the context is a given object Foo.

I have a textbox in readonly mode, whose the text changes according to a selected value in a combobox (which is bind two-way). The value of the textbox uses the values of a lot of fields in Foo.

For now, I have written a converter `Text="{Binding ComboboxValue, Converter={StaticResource MyTextConverter}}`, and code-behind, according to the ComboboxValue, I need to return a string composed of other values of Foo. The problem is I can't access the DataContext in the converter, and I can't pass it. 
If I bind the context without Path (using `Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ConnectionStringTextConverter}}`), it won't trigger every time my value in the combobox changes (normal).

So, is it possible to it that way ? Or I'm forced to use the Selected event of the combobox ?

Thanks

PS: Actually, what I need is to bind the Text property of the textbox on my DataContext (no Path), but I need the binding to be evaluate each time a property change of the object change. Is this possible ?

Comment: Actually, what I need is to bind the Text property of the textbox on my DataContext (no Path), but I need the binding to be evaluate each time a property change of the object change. Is this possible ?

Comment: yes sorry. I have copy/paste my comment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DataContextProxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) utility class like this:

```
Text={Binding ComboBoxValue, Converter={StaticResource MyTextConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}
```

and then in your converter grab the converter parameter and cast it to a DataContextProxy and use its DataSource property.